# Regex to change numbers to a value 1 step lower

Tags: notepad++, regex

i have a regex that i use that changes numbers and increases the value, so if theres a  1 in my txt i turns it into 2, a 0 to 1 and so. Ive been trying to make a new regex that decreases value by 1, so it would turn a 4 into a 3, a 9 into an 8 and so on. But im stuck i cant figure it out, ill post the current regex i use and some examples

```
(0)|(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)
```

Replacement

```
(?{1}1)(?{2}2)(?{3}3)(?{4}4)(?{5}5)(?{6}6)(?{7}7)(?{8}8)(?{9}9)(?{10}0)
```

Now im wondering if its possible to use this same formula but to decrease the numbers

examples

```
james66
fire1
dog 2
lier9
```

to

```
james55
fire0
dog1
lier8
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly the same, just change the values:

Find:

```
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)
```

Replace:

```
(?{1}0)(?{2}1)(?{3}2)(?{4}3)(?{5}4)(?{6}5)(?{7}6)(?{8}7)(?{9}8)
```

And you need to know how do you want to replace `0`

But you'd better write a small script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: could you explain that? For example usually with find and replace and regexes we see potentially lots of regex syntax in the find,, and in the replace we see either plain text or \1 \2 \0  or $0 $1 $2  Yet you show what look a bit like non-capturing parentheses (?...) in the replace. And  could you explain the purpose of the curly braces there. Normally when I see curly braces they are for repetition like 5{3}.  I see what you posted works in changing james66 to james56 i'm just trying to see why?

Comment: @barlop: It is called conditionnal replacement, `(?{1}0)` means `if group 1 is set, then replace it with 0`. Group 1 is set in the find part when we encounter the digit `1`. The same rules apply for all digits.